# AWS EMR - Sqoop import using Cloudera Teradata connector failed to load data in AVRO format

Tags: teradata, sqoop, cloudera, amazon-emr, connector

I have installed cloudera sqoop teradata connector on EMR cluster and tried to import data in avro format. But my sqoop job is failing with below error. I need your help on this issue. I am using Sqoop 1.4.6 version and Teradata driver 14.0 version.By referring some blogs copied below avro jars to /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/

- avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar
- avro-1.7.7.jar

> 18/09/10 13:31:31 INFO common.ConnectorPlugin: load plugins in jar:file:/usr/lib/SQOOP_TERADATA_CONNECTOR-1.5c5/sqoop-connector-teradata-1.5c5.jar!/teradata.connector.plugins.xml
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.sqoop.orm.AvroSchemaGenerator.generate()Lorg/apache/avro/Schema;
>           at com.cloudera.connector.teradata.imports.BaseImportJob.configureInputFormat(BaseImportJob.java:165)
>           at com.cloudera.connector.teradata.imports.TableImportJob.configureInputFormat(TableImportJob.java:32)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:258)
>           at com.cloudera.connector.teradata.TeradataManager.importTable(TeradataManager.java:274)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)

Comment: Hey did you find any way to resolve this?

Comment: @JacobCelestine, Yes. Looks like some issue with cloudera teradata driver. So i used the JDBC connector provided by Teradata which solved my problem.